# How to use joins in a scope?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I've got a page that uses multiple filters and everything works ok except for one filter.  The filter that doesn't work needs to check which `foos` do not have any `bars`.  That is to say no `bar` record will have a `foo_id` matching the `foos` I wish to display.

For this example, let's do a filter on `room` and on `foos` with `no_bars`

I've got something like this in scopes (`foo.rb`):

```
  scope :not_validated, where("mark_validated = false")
  scope :not_located, where("grid_location_id IS NULL")
  scope :no_bars, joins("LEFT JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id where").where("bars.id IS NULL")

  scope :room_1, where("room_id = 1")
  scope :room_2, where("room_id = 2")
```

I have a filter parial:

```
<%= dropdown_tag filter_button_name("Room", "room") do %>
    <li><%= multi_filter_link "room", "room_1"%></li>
    <li><%= multi_filter_link "room", "room_2" %></li>
<% end %>

<%= dropdown_tag filter_button_name("Filter By", "filter") do %>
    <li><%= multi_filter_link "filter", "not_validated" %></li>
    <li><%= multi_filter_link "filter", "not_located" %></li>
    <li><%= multi_filter_link "filter", "no_bars" %></li>
<% end %>
```

When I try to view the `foos` with the `no_bars` filter, I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (bars.id IS NULL)' at line 1: SELECT `foos.*` FROM `foos` LEFT JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id where WHERE (bars.id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :no_bars, joins("LEFT JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id where").where("bars.id IS NULL")
```

I think you want:

```
scope :no_bars, joins("LEFT JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id").where("bars.id IS NULL")
```

Comment: Hot dang, how'd I miss that.  Thanks @user16484.